# readNumberAsArray assignment

Tags: java

> Write a readNumberAsArray method that takes an integer as a parameter and creates a new int array with that number as the length. Subsequently, a corresponding number of int values ​​should be read in with the aid of the IOTools and the array filled with them returned, whereby only single-digit numbers (0-9) should be taken into account as input. If the parameter is negative, the method should return null. For negative or two-digit value entries, the entered value should be replaced by 0. Use a for loop to read in the values. A text output when using the IOTools is not necessary.

My program is not working.

```
import Prog1Tools.IOTools;

package com.company;


public class Main {

    public static void readNumberAsArray(int a) {
    int [] a = new int[];
    int a = IO.Tools.readInteger () ;
    for int (a = 0 ; a<10 ; --a) {
            System.out.println('0');
    for (int a=0; a>10; a++) {
            System.out.println(a);
     for (int a=10; a=>10; a++) {
            System.out.println('0');
        }
    }
        }
    // write your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: "It isn't working" is not a meaningful problem statement. Please [edit] your question to include the details of *how* your program isn't working.

Comment: You have way too many variables named `a`. In fact, you can't declare multiple variables with the same name as you did. You have to give each variable it's own name.

Comment: You import `IOTools` but call a class `IO.Tools` -- might be part of the problem depending on the name the class is actually available under? I think you are doing it slightly too complicated: How about a solution with just one loop?

Comment: I do believe the package declaration comes strictly before the imports.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to just implement what you're asked. Step by step. There's no special logic.

```
public int[] readNumberAsArray(int n) {
    // negative or two-digit values should be replaced with 0
    if (n <= 0 || n > 9)
        return new int[0];

    // creates a new int array with that number as the length
    int[] arr = new int[n];

    // corresponding number of int value should be read in with the aid of the IOTools
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        arr[i] = IO.Tools.readInteger();

    return arr;
}
```

Comment: [Rubber duck debugging](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/)